# GetUsers request timed out

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

```
GET <https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,mail,displayname>
```

the above request is working.
but

```
GET <https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,mail,displayname,onPremisesSyncEnabled>
```

this request is getting timed out.
Any idea  why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question we can answer you because of the differences in the network environment and the operating platform.

I have tested your two request in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and both of them work fine.

So I think other people's test results have no reference value to you.

You should open a support ticket to Azure support team and provide your request id for further investigation.